# CMake with simply project - errors

Tags: cmake, build, compilation

I just started with CMake and wanted to try what I did read in CMake tutorial. I started with the most simply project. Both files (main.c, CMakeLists.txt) are in same directory.

- Source code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
    printf("Hello World");
    
    return 0;
    }
```

- CMakeLists.txt:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
    set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

    project(hello_01)
    add_executable(hello main.c)
```

I expected something like this will be visible in console:

```
    [cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    [cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
    [cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
    [cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    [cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    [cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
    [cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
    [cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
    [cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    [cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    [cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
    [cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
    [cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    [cmake] -- Configuring done (4.1s)
    [cmake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
    [cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Workspace/CMake_study/test/dev_test/build
```

But I get only following error:

> C:\Workspace\CMake_study\cmake_guide>cmake .
> -- Building for: NMake Makefiles CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):   Running
>
> 'nmake' '-?'
>
> failed with:
>
> no such file or directory
>
> CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage CMake
> Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!